# How to check if the Session expires using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, session-state

I want to redirect the user to the "Login page" from anywhere in the application once the session is expired.

How can I accomplish that using JavaScript?

Comment: Why must you use JavaScript? and if you can check it, how would you do it? use setInterval?

Comment: yes if the session is inactive i want the user to redirect to loginpage

Answer (score 4):

A typical implementation of a session requires two things:

1. A cookie in the browser
2. A server side record of the session associated with the number stored in the cookie

These cookies are usually set up as session cookies. They expire when the browser closes. Thus you don't need to worry about testing them to achieve this.

To find out if the session is still valid on the server, you need to (periodically) make an HTTP request to the server (you can do this with Ajax) and have the server respond with information about the life of the session.

A simple solution would be to return true or false, and then redirect (by setting `location.href`) if it is false.

A more efficient solution would be to return the remaining time to live for the session, and use that information to determine when next to check (and redirect if it is 0).
A more

Comment: but usually a server uses a timeout to validate the session, so whenever the user makes a request the timeout is reseted to 0. Therefore if you make a periodical request to the server, the session will never die.. you'd have to change the way your server manages your session.. or maybe i'm wrong =D

Comment: can you tell me how do i periodically check if the session is alive.I know the logic you told i already implemented that with the settime but before that i need to check if the session is alive in my browser..

Comment: `setInterval` and the Ajax library of your choice along with appropriate server side logic for whatever does your session management there.

Comment: @pleasedontbelong — yes, any session resetting mechanism will have to be bypassed.

Comment: Dorward  - it's too bad, because reseting the timeout on each request is a good way to preserve the session, at least is better than telling the user that he has 30 mins to stay connected. And if that's the case you dont really need ajax, all you need is a cookie and periodically check his lifetime.. but i guess that's the only way to solve this question without changing the main idea. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to do a periodic check of session is expired, the best thing you can do is you can check when event is fired on the front end, Say like before submit / before click etc.
Server time is a key resources we need to manage to give better app performance.